# How do I fix this error tha keeps popping when I run my app What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'

Tags: android, kotlin

I keep getting this error when I try to start my React Native app, what might be wrong?

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'.
> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunnerWithWorkers$GradleKotlinCompilerWorkAction
   > Compilation error. See log for more details

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

Here is my build.gradle file in Android folder

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "34.0.0"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 34
        targetSdkVersion = 34
        ndkVersion = "25.1.8937393"
        kotlinVersion = "1.9.22"
    }
    

    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
   
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.1")
        classpath("com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin")
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.9.22")
    }
}

apply plugin: "com.facebook.react.rootproject"
```

Comment: Well, it does say `Compilation error. See log for more details`...

Comment: yes, even when I do the instructions it gave, I still got this same error, how do I fix this then?

Comment: It depends on "the instructions it gave".

Comment: it's clearly written with the question below the "Compilation err. log for more details"

Comment: Those instructions are too general. What you really need to do is look in the log for more details.